# set default value to an outputText in jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

How can I set a default value to my `outputText` so that the user doesn't have to enter it each time?

```
    <h:inputText value= "#{bean.cit.nationality}" id="nationality"/>
```

I would like to set the value to `"American"` as a default value to `nationality`.

Comment: Do it in a corresponding/associated managed bean such as a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. Either set the default value in the bean data or use javascript/jquery to set the html input text value.

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.cit.nationality}" id="nationality"/>
    <script>$("#formId\\:nationality}").val() = "American"</script>
</h:form>
```

Or you can use a more generic approach to find the client component within its parent or naming container:

```
$("##{component.namingContainer.findComponent('nationality').clientId}")
```

You can also use a utility method to escape the JSF colon to reduce conflicts with jquery.

```
$("(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formId:nationality')")
```